# Call the render function when creating a new view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I was looking to this example [Introduction to Backbone.js Part 2](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/introduction-to-backbone-js-part-2-views-video-tutorial/).

In this example the render function is called when I click on button:

```
events: {
    "click button": "render"
},
```

How can I call the render function when the model is loaded?

```
var view = new View({ model: model });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just to add the following line `this.render();` to your initialize function in your View Class

```
initialize: function()
{
    this.template = $('#list-template').children();
    this.render();
},
```